# Merge Spreadsheets

Tags: numbers

[Numbers, macOS]

I need to merge data in 2 spreadsheets / tables. Both of them contain contact information. The second table contains a column that I want to append to the first table.
Now, I can't just copy/paste the column, because even though the two tables contain the same column `A`, they don't contain an equal amount of rows.
For illustration, I put sample tables below.

**Table #1**

```
Name       Address          Phone
Mr. One    First Address    45120354554
Ms. Two    Second Address   42874518933
Mr. Three  Third Address    74125986538
Mr. Four   Fourth Address   95645740200
```

**Table #2**

```
Name       Address          Website
Mr. One    First Address    a@b.com
Mr. Three  Third Address    e@a.com
```

How could I append the `Website` column to table #1, so that if the `Name` column matches, it pastes what it finds in table #2's `Website` column to get the result shown below?

**Target Table**

```
Name       Address          Phone         Website
Mr. One    First Address    45120354554   a@b.com
Ms. Two    Second Address   42874518933   
Mr. Three  Third Address    74125986538   e@a.com
Mr. Four   Fourth Address   95645740200
```

I'm sorry if this is hard to understand. I don't really know how to put it, so feel free to ask any question!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This operation is called a "Left Join" in database lingo. I don't know if it's possible directly in Numbers, but maybe at least knowing the term can help you search better.

Comment: In fact I think the most robust solution would actually be to export your spreadsheets as CSVs, import them into a database (macOS comes with a database engine called SQLite already installed), do a join in the database, and then export a CSV to re-import into Numbers.

Comment: I'm working on a Numbers-only solution, however. Is it possible that the `Address` columns disagree between tables? If so, how do you want to handle it?

Comment: Technically that is not possible, no. What is possible, however, is that table #2 contains the "same" row multiple times. ("same" as in same `name` column)

Comment: Actually, I'd not mind removing same columns except the `name` column obviously and leaving all the columns that table #2 contains, but table #1 does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's make some assumptions:

1. The only column in Table 2 you care about is `Website`
2. All of the data in both `Name` columns is 100% correct and can be matched "exactly" (i.e. not fuzzily)
3. The columns are labeled with a "header" row (the dark gray background by default)
4. The tables are named `Table 1` and `Table 2`
5. The data starts on row `2` in both tables

Therefore we are simply going to take the desired values from `Table 2::Website` (Mac Numbers formula notation for "Column `Website` in `Table 2`") and plop them into `Table 1::D`.

This is actually *very* easy to do, and it's one of those standard spreadsheet tricks that's great to have in your back pocket. An Internet search for something like "index match excel" and "vlookup excel" will give you tons of results.

**Note for Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets users**: write `!` instead of `::`, and put single-quotes `'` around any table name with spaces in it. Should be the same result.

### Solution 1 (general technique)

In the first row of `Table 1::Website`, put this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Website, MATCH(A2, Table 2::Name, 0), 1), "")
```

Unfortunately, because Numbers thinks it's smarter than you are, it won't let me paste this in -- you'll apparently have to type it by hand. Then click and drag the yellow dot on the bottom of the cell all the way down to the bottom.

Let's unpack this from the inside out.

`MATCH`

Official documentation: http://help.apple.com/functions/mac/7.0/#/ffa59a83d3

`MATCH` takes the following arguments:

1. Value to search for
2. Range of values to search in
3. Search "mode"

and returns the first position (1, 2, 3, etc.) in #2 that matches the value in #1. The documentation has more about argument #3, but 9 times out of 10 you will want to set it to `0`,

`INDEX`

Official documentation: http://help.apple.com/functions/mac/7.0/#/ffa59b4edb

`INDEX` takes the following arguments:

1. A range of cells to select from
2. A row in that range to select
3. A column in that range to select
4. An area number to use in the selected cell

We want to select from `Table 2::Website`, so that's what goes in to #1. The result of the `MATCH` call above gives us the row number we want, so that goes into #2. There's only one column in that range, so we know we want to put `1` into 3. If #4 is omitted, it defaults to `1`. Don't worry about this, just leave it out.

`IFERROR`

Official documentation:

`IFERROR` takes the following arguments:

1. A value to check for errors
2. A replacement value if there's an error

This one is self-explanatory. If `INDEX` fails, it will produce an error. Use this to replace those errors with blanks (or something else if you desire).

### Solution 2 (shortcut)

You can simplify this query with a shortcut function:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Table 2::Name:Website, 3, 0), "")
```

What this does is "vertically looks up" `A2` in the range `Table 2::Name:Website` and returns the value in column `3` that from the row it found. The `0` at the end specifies to look for an exact, rather than approximate, match. The `IFERROR` part is identical.

Comment: Dang. Take my upvote for the effort. I'll have a look later and will let you know if it works for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sooo here we go. I can't get solution #1 to work somehow. See my [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmwcfeyuer070vd/Screen%20Shot%202017-01-11%20at%2011.16.05.png?dl=0), anything wrong there? (I just renamed `Website` to `Status`) Solution #2, however, does work for me. Thanks!

Comment: @LinusG. glad #2 worked. It looks like you have the wrong value in the third argument to `MATCH`.

Comment: solution 1 worked great for me